# Keeping filters in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

What I would like to achive is:

- I go to admin site, apply some filters to the list of objects
- I click and object edit, edit, edit, hit 'Save'
- Site takes me to the list of objects... unfiltered. I'd like to have the filter from step 1 remembered and applied.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this.  The filtering does not seem to be saved in any session variable.

Clicking back twice is the normal method, but it can be unweildy and annoying if you've just changed an object so that it should no longer be shown using your filter.

If it's just a one-off, click back twice or go through the filtering again, it's the easiest way.

If you're going to be filtering more often, or you just want to learn about hacking the admin (which is pretty open and easy), you'll want to write a [FilterSpec](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/filterspecs.py).

Have a look [here](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1051/) and [here](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/587/) for examples of people writing their own.

A really, really terrible way to do this would be to edit the admin interface so that after you click "Save", you are redirected to you filtered URL.  I wouldn't recommend this at all, but it's an option.

Another fairly simple way to do this would be to write a generic view to show your filtered objects, then use Django forms to edit the items from there.  I'd have a look at this, you'll be stunned just how little code you have to write to get a simple view/edit page going.

Comment: Writing a `FilterSpec` isn't enough. It's actually the view which controls the queryset, and that takes its parameters from `request.GET`. All `FilterSpec`s really do is affect the display of filter options.

Comment: Also, redirecting to a filtered URL is not "really, really terrible". The filter options should be explicit in the URL. It would be better than having a invisible session variable affect the queryset without this being evident in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Click 2 times "Back"?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple hack to do this, but it's not a general solution and requires modifying every `ModelAdmin` which you want to support this. Maybe there is a general way to do this, but I've not spent the time to solve it on a general level.

The first step is to write a custom `FilterSpec` for the filter (see Harley's post for links that will help) which saves the chosen filter value in the session (and deletes it when no longer wanted).

```
# in cust_admin/filterspecs.py
from django.contrib.admin.filterspecs import FilterSpec, ChoicesFilterSpec

class MyFilterSpec(ChoicesFilterSpec):

    def __init__(self, f, request, params, model, model_admin):
        super(MyFilterSpec, self).__init__(f, request, params, model,
                                           model_admin)
        if self.lookup_val is not None:
            request.session[self.lookup_kwarg] = self.lookup_val
        elif self.lookup_kwarg in request.session:
            del(request.session[self.lookup_kwarg])

# Register the filter with a test function which will apply it to any field
# with a my_filter attribute equal to True
FilterSpec.filter_specs.insert(0, (lambda f: getattr(f, 'my_filter', False),
                               MyFilterSpec))
```

You must import the module this is in somewhere, for example your `urls.py`:

```
# in urls.py
from cust_admin import filterspecs
```

Set a property on the field you want to apply the filter to:

```
# in models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = Models.IntegerField(choices=MY_CHOICES)
    my_field.my_filter = True
```

In a custom `ModelAdmin` class, override the `change_view` method, so that after the user clicks **save**, they are returned to the list view with their filter field value added to the URL.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        result = super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
                                                       extra_context)
        if '_save' in request.POST:
            if 'my_field__exact' in request.session:
                result['Location'] = '/admin/myapp/mymodel/?my_field__exact=%s' \
                                     % request.session['my_field__exact']
        return result
```

Comment: Does this mean that every time you view the model's admin page it will be filtered?  Or does it just remember the filter you've applied for a session?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to embed the filter in the queryset.

You can dynamically create a proxy model with a manager that filters the way you want, then call admin.site.register() to create a new model admin. All the links would then be relative to this view.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its better to override methods from ModelAdmin `changelist_view` and `change_view`:

Like so:

```
class FakturaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

[...]

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    result = super(FakturaAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=None)
    request.session['qdict'] = request.GET
    return result

def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
    result = super(FakturaAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
    try:
        result['location'] = result['location']+"?"+request.session['qdict'].urlencode()
    except:
        pass
    return result
```

As you wish, after save object you go back to list of objects with active filters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a change request at the Django project asking for exactly this functionality.

All it's waiting for to be checked in is some tests and documentation. You could write those, and help the whole project, or you could just take the proposed patch (near the bottom of the page) and try it out.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6903

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added to Django as part of the 1.6 release and is enabled now by default. It is described in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#minor-features):

> ModelAdmin now preserves filters on the list view after creating,
>   editing or deleting an object. It’s possible to restore the previous
>   behavior of clearing filters by setting the preserve_filters attribute
>   to False.