# How to preserve filter selection after save in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

First, I did look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177492/keeping-filters-in-django-admin), but its over a year old.  Surely now there is a good way in Django 1.1.1 to carry filter selection forward after a user clicks the save button in the Admin.

In a table with thousands of records, filtering is essential.  And if a user makes several filter choices that effort shouldn't have to be repeated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is still the same: out of the box, Django doesn't support this behavior. There are a couple of tickets in the issue tracker with patches: [#3777](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3777), [#6903](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6903). The middleware class in [this comment](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3777#comment:4) works without modifying Django code.

Comment: I like the middleware solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, solves a BIG issue for my users! That patch has been sitting there for 6 years...

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been added to Django as part of the 1.6 release and is enabled now by default. It is described in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#minor-features):

> ModelAdmin now preserves filters on the list view after creating,
>   editing or deleting an object. It’s possible to restore the previous
>   behavior of clearing filters by setting the preserve_filters attribute
>   to False.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use this snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2531/

```
Class Modeladmin_perso(admin.ModelAdmin):
def add_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    result = super(Modeladmin_perso, self).add_view(request, *args, **kwargs )

   # Look at the referer for a query string '^.*\?.*$'
    ref = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
    if ref.find('?') != -1:
        # We've got a query string, set the session value
        request.session['filtered'] =  ref

    if request.POST.has_key('_save'):
        """
        We only kick into action if we've saved and if
        there is a session key of 'filtered', then we
        delete the key.
        """
        try:
            if request.session['filtered'] is not None:
                result['Location'] = request.session['filtered']
                request.session['filtered'] = None
        except:
            pass
    return result
"""
Used to redirect users back to their filtered list of locations if there were any
"""
def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context={}):
    """
    save the referer of the page to return to the filtered
    change_list after saving the page
    """
    result = super(Modeladmin_perso, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context )

    # Look at the referer for a query string '^.*\?.*$'
    ref = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
    if ref.find('?') != -1:
        # We've got a query string, set the session value
        request.session['filtered'] =  ref

    if request.POST.has_key('_save'):
        """
        We only kick into action if we've saved and if
        there is a session key of 'filtered', then we
        delete the key.
        """
        try:
            if request.session['filtered'] is not None:
                result['Location'] = request.session['filtered']
                request.session['filtered'] = None
        except:
            pass
    return result
```

the good thing is you don't have to hack anything.

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been a request to the Django project for a long time (the [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6903) was opened 5 years ago).

Fortunately this annoying behavior was [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/c86a9b63984f6692d478f6f70e3c78de4ec41814) in trunk. Expect it to be included in Django 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did inside `render_change_form` to generate a back button with `preserved_filters`.

```py
def generate_back_url(self, request):
    opts = self.model._meta
    post_url = reverse(
        "admin:%s_%s_changelist" % (opts.app_label, opts.model_name),
        current_app=self.admin_site.name,
    )
    preserved_filters = self.get_preserved_filters(request)
    return add_preserved_filters(
        {"preserved_filters": preserved_filters, "opts": opts}, post_url
    )
```